# Malformed definition: Nonlinear patterns not allowed in sequential mode

Tags: isabelle

I have defined the following function:

```
fun count:: "'a ⇒ 'a list ⇒ nat" where
"count a Nil = 0" |
"count a (Cons b xs) = (count a xs)" |
"count a (Cons a xs) = (count a xs) + (Suc 0)"
```

It should count the number of occurrences of element a in a list with elemnts of the same type with a. I get the following error:

```
Malformed definition:
Nonlinear patterns not allowed in sequential mode.
⋀a xs. count a (a # xs) = count a xs + Suc 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With respect to patterns, ‘linear’ means that each free variable only occurs *once*. In your third line, the pattern on the left-hand side contains `a` twice, which makes it non-linear. This is not supported by the ‘sequential’ mode of the function package. This is the mode in which you can specify possibly overlapping function equations one after another and the first one that matches is the one that counts. This is also the mode that the ‘fun’ command uses and which is what functional programming languages like Haskell typically do (note that these usually don't allow non-linear patterns either).

You basically have two possibilities here: If you absolutely want to use non-linear patterns, you can write

```
function count:: "'a ⇒ 'a list ⇒ nat" where
  "count a Nil = 0"
| "a ≠ b ⟹ count a (Cons b xs) = (count a xs)"
| "count a (Cons a xs) = (count a xs) + (Suc 0)"
  by (metis neq_Nil_conv surj_pair) auto
termination by lexicographic_order
```

Note that you have to show the fact that the patterns are exhaustive and non-overlapping manually, as well as termination. ‘fun’ is less powerful but does all of these things automatically.

The much easier and better way is to just reformulate your definition in a way that is more palatable to the system's automation:

```
fun count:: "'a ⇒ 'a list ⇒ nat" where
  "count a Nil = 0"
| "count a (Cons b xs) = (count a xs) + (if a = b then 1 else 0)‹›
```

This is almost always preferable for a variety of reasons (shorter, easier, works better with code generation).

For more information on the function package, consult the [documentation](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2018/doc/functions.pdf). It's a very powerful and versatile tool, but if you can get what you want with only ‘fun’, that's usually the way you want to go.